# Eclipse System property

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to set the value of a system property java.library.path to c:\somepath. i know that i need to add this in the vm args section. Could some please provide the actual syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument is

```
-Djava.library.path=c:/somepath
```

To test if it's correct:

```
String key = "java.library.path";
System.out.printf("%s=%s%n", key, System.getProperty(key));
```

Comment: use this after `-vmargs`, e.g. `eclipse -vmargs -Djava.library.path=...`

Comment: I guess he wanted to add the parameter to a runtime configuration in eclipse itself.

Comment: yes i wanted to add the parameter at runtime config in eclipse, thanks guys for the response